# Intersections/unions of open/closed schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I am attempting to determine whether the following statements are correct. In all of these statement, I need to consider both the finite and the infinite case:

Let $A$ be an $R$-algebra, $X$ denote some affine scheme, $P$ denote some closed subscheme and $Q$ denote some open subscheme. The statements are:

**By finite case, I mean taking the union of finitely many open/closed subschemes. Same for the so-called infinite case**

(1)$(P_1 ∩ P_2)(A) = P_1(A) ∩ P_2(A)$

True.

(2)$(\bigcap _{\alpha\in I}P_{\alpha})(A)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} (P_{\alpha}(A))$

Ture.

(3)$(P_1 ∪ P_2)(A) = P_1(A) ∪ P_2(A)$

It holds for $C$ to be a field, but is not true in general.

(4)$(\bigcup _{\alpha\in I}P_{\alpha})(A)=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} (P_{\alpha}(A))$

Does not make sense.

(5)$(Q_1 ∩ Q_2)(A) = Q_1(A) ∩ Q_2(A)$

True.

(6)$(\bigcap _{\alpha\in I}Q_{\alpha})(A)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} (Q_{\alpha}(A))$

True

(7)$(Q_1 ∪ Q_2)(A) = Q_1(A) ∪ Q_2(A)$(**This is the main part that I am not sure**)

It is true for field, but I can neither prove it is true in general nor find some counter examples yet. **So could someone please prove it or disprove it by finding some counter examples?**

(8)$(\bigcup _{\alpha\in I}Q_{\alpha})(A)=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} (Q_{\alpha}(A))$

$ (X \setminus P)(A) = X(A) \setminus P(A)$

It is true when $A$ is a field, but doesn't hold in general, a quick example could be taking $R=\Bbb C, A=\Bbb C[t], X$ is the affine line, and $P= Spec_R(R)$ is the vanishing locus of the polynomial $x\in R[x]$ Then $P(A)=\{0\}$, $(X\setminus P)(A)=Spec_R(\Bbb C[x,y]/\langle xy-1\rangle)(\Bbb C[t])=\text{units in $\Bbb C$}$, which is not the whole $\Bbb C[t]\setminus \{0\}$.

**For all of these parts, could someone please tell me if I am correct? And for the 4th statement, I have stuck for some time, so I would be very appreciate if someone could prove it or give some examples. Reference or ideas are also appreciate. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: It would make your question more readable if you could clarify the $C$ and $A$ and expand on what you mean by 'finite and infinite case'. That said, I think this is a good question. For the part you're not sure, consider the case where $Q_1 \cup Q_2 = X = Spec(A)$ to find a counterexample.

Comment: @Johann I think of such a scheme... Consider $Q_1$ to be the open subscheme of $\Bbb A^2$(affine $2$-space) which is the complement of the subscheme: points with invertible $x$-coordinate. And $Q_2$ to be the open subscheme of $\Bbb A^2$ which is the complement of "points with invertible $y$-coordinte". So $Q_1\cup Q_2\cong Spec(R[x,y]/<xy>)$. But I am unsure how to proceed...Am I on the right track?

Comment: Edited to make the statements more explicit.

Comment: Your $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ look closed to me. Anyways, to get a feel for this question, you could try a very easy case first, like $X = Spec(k \times k)$ for a field $k$. There you only have two points, both of which are open an closed.